# is Visual C++ actually generating blatantly incorrect code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, compilation

So I'm debugging my DPLL implementation and it's not quite working right so I step through the code line by line in the debugger, it gets to a return statement but the thing is it doesn't return, it just keeps on executing the same function. WTF I thought, am I really seeing this? So I looked at the dissasembly and sure enough one of the return statements jumps to the wrong place. Never have I seen VS generate incorrect code so I'm wondering if I screwed up somewhere but I can't find anything. The jump is incorrect even when compiling with all optimizations off.

This illustrates whats going on.

```
bool dpll(std::vector<clause> f)
{
    unitPropagate(f);

    if(checkFalseClause(f))
    {
        return false; //je dpll+5Fh (0C01D1Fh) <-- Totally wrong jump adress
    }
    else if(checkAllClausesTrue(f))
    {
        return true; //jmp dpll+206h (0C01EC6h) <-- this is fine
    }
    else
    {
        atom l = chooseLiteral(f); //this is where the jump ends up (0C01D1Fh)

        std::vector<clause> a = makeDuplicate(f);
        replaceInstancesOf(a, l, true);

        std::vector<clause> b = makeDuplicate(f);
        replaceInstancesOf(b, l, false);

        return dpll(a) | dpll(b);
    }

    //this is where the jump is supposed to go (0C01EC6h)
}
```

So my question is, is Visual Studio actually broken or have I misunderstood something? Has anyone run into something like this before?

The version is Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 if that makes a difference, the code is generated for x86_32.

Here's the full dissasembly if anyone's interested:

```
00C01CC0  push        ebp  
00C01CC1  mov         ebp,esp  
00C01CC3  push        0FFFFFFFFh  
00C01CC5  push        0C08FF0h  
00C01CCA  mov         eax,dword ptr fs:[00000000h]  
00C01CD0  push        eax  
00C01CD1  sub         esp,40h  
00C01CD4  mov         eax,dword ptr [__security_cookie (0C0D008h)]  
00C01CD9  xor         eax,ebp  
00C01CDB  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax  
00C01CDE  push        ebx  
00C01CDF  push        esi  
00C01CE0  push        eax  
00C01CE1  lea         eax,[ebp-0Ch]  
00C01CE4  mov         dword ptr fs:[00000000h],eax  
bool dpll(std::vector<clause> f)
00C01CEA  lea         ecx,[f]  
00C01CED  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  
00C01CF4  call        unitPropagate (0C01950h)  
{
    unitPropagate(f);
00C01CF9  lea         ecx,[f]  
00C01CFC  call        checkFalseClause (0C01660h)  
00C01D01  test        al,al  
00C01D03  je          dpll+4Ch (0C01D0Ch)  
00C01D05  xor         bh,bh  
00C01D07  jmp         dpll+206h (0C01EC6h)  

    if(checkFalseClause(f))
    {
        return false;
00C01D0C  lea         ecx,[f]  
00C01D0F  call        checkAllClausesTrue (0C014F0h)  
00C01D14  test        al,al  
00C01D16  je          dpll+5Fh (0C01D1Fh)  
    }
    else if(checkAllClausesTrue(f))
00C01D18  mov         bh,1  
00C01D1A  jmp         dpll+206h (0C01EC6h)  
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
00C01D1F  lea         edx,[f]  
00C01D22  lea         ecx,[l]  
00C01D25  call        chooseLiteral (0C013D0h)  
00C01D2A  mov         byte ptr [ebp-4],1  
    {
        atom l = chooseLiteral(f);
00C01D2E  lea         edx,[f]  
00C01D31  xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
00C01D34  mov         dword ptr [ebp-20h],0  
00C01D3B  lea         ecx,[a]  
00C01D3E  movq        mmword ptr [a],xmm0  
00C01D43  call        makeDuplicate (0C01A30h)  
00C01D48  mov         byte ptr [ebp-4],2  

00C01D4C  sub         esp,20h  
00C01D4F  mov         esi,esp  
00C01D51  mov         bl,1  
00C01D53  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],esi  
00C01D56  lea         ecx,[esi+4]  
00C01D59  mov         al,byte ptr [l]  
00C01D5C  mov         byte ptr [esi],al  
00C01D5E  mov         dword ptr [ecx+14h],0Fh  
00C01D65  mov         dword ptr [ecx+10h],0  
00C01D6C  cmp         dword ptr [ecx+14h],10h  
00C01D70  jb          dpll+0B6h (0C01D76h)  
00C01D72  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx]  
00C01D74  jmp         dpll+0B8h (0C01D78h)  
00C01D76  mov         eax,ecx  
00C01D78  push        0FFFFFFFFh  

00C01D7A  mov         byte ptr [eax],0  
00C01D7D  lea         eax,[ebp-44h]  
00C01D80  push        0  
00C01D82  push        eax  
00C01D83  call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign (0C02A80h)  
00C01D88  mov         al,byte ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
00C01D8B  lea         ecx,[a]  
00C01D8E  mov         byte ptr [esi+1Ch],al  
00C01D91  mov         dl,bl  
00C01D93  mov         al,byte ptr [ebp-2Bh]  
00C01D96  mov         byte ptr [esi+1Dh],al  
00C01D99  call        replaceInstancesOf (0C017D0h)  
00C01D9E  xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
00C01DA1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],0  
        std::vector<clause> a = makeDuplicate(f);
        replaceInstancesOf(a, l, true);
00C01DA8  lea         edx,[f]  
        std::vector<clause> a = makeDuplicate(f);
        replaceInstancesOf(a, l, true);
00C01DAB  movq        mmword ptr [b],xmm0  
00C01DB0  lea         ecx,[b]  
00C01DB3  call        makeDuplicate (0C01A30h)  

00C01DB8  mov         esi,esp  
00C01DBA  mov         byte ptr [ebp-4],3  
00C01DBE  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],esi  
00C01DC1  lea         ecx,[esi+4]  
00C01DC4  mov         al,byte ptr [l]  
00C01DC7  xor         bl,bl  
00C01DC9  push        0FFFFFFFFh  
00C01DCB  mov         byte ptr [esi],al  
00C01DCD  lea         eax,[ebp-44h]  
00C01DD0  push        0  
00C01DD2  mov         dword ptr [ecx+14h],0Fh  
00C01DD9  mov         dword ptr [ecx+10h],0  
00C01DE0  push        eax  
00C01DE1  mov         byte ptr [ecx],bl  
00C01DE3  call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign (0C02A80h)  
00C01DE8  mov         al,byte ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
00C01DEB  lea         ecx,[b]  
00C01DEE  mov         byte ptr [esi+1Ch],al  
00C01DF1  mov         dl,bl  
00C01DF3  mov         al,byte ptr [ebp-2Bh]  
00C01DF6  mov         byte ptr [esi+1Dh],al  
00C01DF9  call        replaceInstancesOf (0C017D0h)  
        std::vector<clause> b = makeDuplicate(f);
        replaceInstancesOf(b, l, false);
00C01DFE  add         esp,14h  
00C01E01  lea         eax,[a]  
00C01E04  mov         ecx,esp  
00C01E06  push        eax  
00C01E07  call        std::vector<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> >,std::allocator<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > > >::vector<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> >,std::allocator<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > > > (0C02420h)  
00C01E0C  call        dpll (0C01CC0h)  
00C01E11  mov         bl,al  
00C01E13  mov         ecx,esp  
00C01E15  lea         eax,[b]  
00C01E18  push        eax  
00C01E19  call        std::vector<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> >,std::allocator<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > > >::vector<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> >,std::allocator<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > > > (0C02420h)  
00C01E1E  call        dpll (0C01CC0h)  
00C01E23  mov         ecx,dword ptr [b]  
00C01E26  mov         bh,al  
00C01E28  add         esp,0Ch  
00C01E2B  or          bh,bl  
00C01E2D  test        ecx,ecx  
00C01E2F  je          dpll+1B4h (0C01E74h)  
00C01E31  push        dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
00C01E34  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
00C01E37  push        ecx  
00C01E38  call        std::_Destroy_range1<std::allocator<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > >,std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > *> (0C035E0h)  
00C01E3D  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
00C01E40  mov         eax,2AAAAAABh  
00C01E45  mov         esi,dword ptr [b]  
00C01E48  add         esp,8  
00C01E4B  sub         ecx,esi  
00C01E4D  imul        ecx  
00C01E4F  sar         edx,1  
00C01E51  mov         eax,edx  
00C01E53  shr         eax,1Fh  
00C01E56  add         eax,edx  
00C01E58  push        eax  
00C01E59  push        esi  
00C01E5A  call        std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > > >::deallocate (0C02D20h)  
00C01E5F  mov         dword ptr [b],0  
00C01E66  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],0  
00C01E6D  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],0  
00C01E74  mov         ecx,dword ptr [a]  
00C01E77  test        ecx,ecx  
00C01E79  je          dpll+1FEh (0C01EBEh)  
00C01E7B  push        dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
00C01E7E  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-24h]  
00C01E81  push        ecx  
00C01E82  call        std::_Destroy_range1<std::allocator<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > >,std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > *> (0C035E0h)  
00C01E87  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-20h]  
00C01E8A  mov         eax,2AAAAAABh  
00C01E8F  mov         esi,dword ptr [a]  
00C01E92  add         esp,8  
00C01E95  sub         ecx,esi  
00C01E97  imul        ecx  
00C01E99  sar         edx,1  
00C01E9B  mov         eax,edx  
00C01E9D  shr         eax,1Fh  
00C01EA0  add         eax,edx  
00C01EA2  push        eax  
00C01EA3  push        esi  
00C01EA4  call        std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > > >::deallocate (0C02D20h)  
00C01EA9  mov         dword ptr [a],0  
00C01EB0  mov         dword ptr [ebp-24h],0  
00C01EB7  mov         dword ptr [ebp-20h],0  
00C01EBE  lea         ecx,[ebp-44h]  
00C01EC1  call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (0C027A0h)  
00C01EC6  mov         ecx,dword ptr [f]  
00C01EC9  test        ecx,ecx  
00C01ECB  je          dpll+23Bh (0C01EFBh)  
00C01ECD  push        dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
00C01ED0  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
00C01ED3  push        ecx  
00C01ED4  call        std::_Destroy_range1<std::allocator<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > >,std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > *> (0C035E0h)  
00C01ED9  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+10h]  
00C01EDC  mov         eax,2AAAAAABh  
00C01EE1  mov         esi,dword ptr [f]  
00C01EE4  add         esp,8  
00C01EE7  sub         ecx,esi  
00C01EE9  imul        ecx  
00C01EEB  sar         edx,1  
00C01EED  mov         ecx,edx  
00C01EEF  shr         ecx,1Fh  
00C01EF2  add         ecx,edx  
00C01EF4  push        ecx  
00C01EF5  push        esi  
00C01EF6  call        std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::vector<atom,std::allocator<atom> > > >::deallocate (0C02D20h)  
00C01EFB  mov         al,bh  

00C01EFD  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
00C01F00  mov         dword ptr fs:[0],ecx  
00C01F07  pop         ecx  
00C01F08  pop         esi  
00C01F09  pop         ebx  
00C01F0A  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-10h]  
00C01F0D  xor         ecx,ebp  
00C01F0F  call        __security_check_cookie (0C080CCh)  
00C01F14  mov         esp,ebp  
00C01F16  pop         ebp  
00C01F17  ret
```

Comment: Mystery abbreviations?  DPLL?

Comment: Might be undefined behavior.  The compiler is allowed to optimize assuming that something undefined will not happen so that can cause all sorts of crazy things.

Comment: 0C01D1Fh is actually before `if (checkAllClausesTrue(f))`. If's just that the source is incorrectly interleaved with the assembly.

Comment: @NathanOliver thats what I thought, but as I said optimization is OFF, and I can't see anthing wrong with the code.

Comment: I would consider it the height of hubris to assume that defects are due to bad code generation by C++.  The code generator has been used by a huge audience that's likely to report and fix defects over a long period of time.  It's far more likely that it's either a mistake in your code or a faulty understanding.

Comment: @duffymo I'm not saying there isn't anything wrong with my code, but if there is I'm hoping someone could point it out so I can fix it.

Comment: @PgrAm: Sorry, I mixed up the address and the fn call in the comment above. But you should get the idea, source is incorrectly interleaved in the debugger, but there is nothing wrong with the assembly. Most likely the repeated calls are due to the recursion in the last branch.

Comment: @zipzit if you're interested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm, I didn't really think it was important to my question

Comment: @duffymo: absolutely, in my opinion msvc2015 is extremely good. If you think the compiler is faulty then an example from int main() is the only appropriate example.

Comment: @Bathsheba I agree msvc2015 is excellent and has always been reliable for me. It's not unreasonable to assume that occasionally they could make a mistake too as I just have. If I was certain that the compiler was faulty I wouldn't have asked the community I would just have reported a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source interleaving is wrong. This is the correct place you want to look at:

```
00C01CFC  call        checkFalseClause (0C01660h)  
00C01D01  test        al,al  
00C01D03  je          dpll+4Ch (0C01D0Ch)  
00C01D05  xor         bh,bh  
00C01D07  jmp         dpll+206h (0C01EC6h)
```

As you can see, it goes to the expected address if the return value was nonzero.

The part you looked at is actually for the `else if(checkAllClausesTrue(f))` and the jump is the one going to the `else` clause because the compiler negated the condition.

Comment: Oops seems like I was wrong! just a case of the debugger playing tricks on me. I should have spent more time looking at the disassembly. Turns out there was a bug in the checkAllClausesTrue() function